# Как сделать, что бы див был посередине?

Tags: html, css

Предположим есть 2 вложенных дива

```
  <div id="wrapper"><div id="center"></div></div>
```

- `#wrapper` занимает весь экран
- `#center` внутри него, и должен иметь одинаковые отступы с двух сторон от него, даже при уменьшении или увеличении экрана

Как мне сделать див `#center`, чтобы он занимал середину в `#wrapper`, имея (width в 2 раза меньше) при этом, чтобы у него были одинаковые отступы от `#wrapper`.

Короче, если легче будет, зайдите на Facebook и там див с классом gradientContent. Как сделать также?

Comment:     #center { margin: 0px auto; } //все просто!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#center { width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Работает только, если у `#center` известна (задана) ширина.

В ином случае [как-то так](http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm):

```
#wrapper { float: left; position: relative; left: 50%; }
#center { float: left; position: relative; left: -50%; }
#center::after { content: " "; display: block; height: 0;
                 visibility: hidden; clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Выровнять по горизонтали (1 способ)

```
#center{margin: 0 auto;}
```

Выровнять по горизонтали (2 способ)

```
#wrapper{display: flex; justify-content: center;}
```

Выровнять по вертикали

```
 #wrapper{display: flex; align-items: center;}
```